Best Practices for Applying Difference-in-Differences in Panel Data Analysis: Addressing Imbalance and Identifying Suitable Matching Techniques
I am conducting a study on the impact of the African Growth and Opportunity Act (AGOA) on apparel exports from Sub-Saharan Africa using panel data, including 20 treatment countries under the Special Rule and 7 control countries. I'm considering using a Difference-in-Differences (DiD) approach and seek advice on best practices for applying DiD in this context, particularly how to address the imbalance between a smaller control group and a larger treatment group. Additionally, I'm interested in recommendations for suitable matching techniques for this type of panel data?

Welcome to CV. Why do you suspect the imbalance is problematic? And why do you want to use matching methods? Why is this necessary in your particular context?

Thank you for the questions. The imbalance between my treatment and control groups is concerning because it might introduce biases affecting the reliability of my analysis. Essentially, a smaller control group may not adequately represent the counterfactual scenario needed to isolate the effect of the treatment. I'm considering matching methods to enhance the comparability between these groups, ensuring that any observed effects more accurately reflect the impact of the policy rather than underlying differences between the groups
